# Get ID of maximum occurence in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, ssms

`EpisodeID`s are unique and have unique episode orders, but different `episodeID`s can share the same `SpellID`.
I'm trying to select so that I can find the `EpisodeID`s that have the highest order within each `SpellID`.
I have tried the following but is not doing what its supposed, any help?

heres an example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9nXI.png)
the idea is to only select the rows that out of the same `SpellID`, they have the highest order number

```
SELECT TOP(100) Spell_ID,Episode_ID, MAX(Episode_Order) AS M
From [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing]
Group by Spell_ID, Episode_ID
```

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not quite easy [to me] to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Just added some extra info, hope it's more helpful

Answer (score 0):

There might be a cleaner solution but the first thing that comes to mind is to use a cte

```
;with cte as (
select spell_id, MAX(episode_order) as M from [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing]
Group by Spell_ID
)
select t.spell_id, t.episode_id, t.episode_order from [dbo].[Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing] t
join cte on cte.spell_id = t.spell_id and cte.M = t.episode_order
```

Answer (score 0):

> idea is to only select the rows that out of the same SpellID, they have the highest order number

You can use window functions:

```
select cmiel.*
from (select cmiel.*,
             rank() over (partition by spell_id order by episode_order desc) as seqnum
      from Client_MidEssex_Inpatient_Episodes_Landing cmiel
     ) cmiel
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used both of the select columns in an inner join statement with two conditions. Because there are only unique combinations of both, there was no need for a 3rd value, hence no need for the ID. Thank you for the replies.